# Handle pop up alert like in pop up in c#

Tags: c#, automation

How can i click open zoom meeting button in c#?
Swith.to.alert is not working, i tried most of the ways but still no luck.
[image]

I tried switch.to.alert and most of the ways.
I am using c# mstest unit framework.